# Java iterative reading of Files

Tags: java, file, loops, xml-parsing, directory

at the moment I'm having a problem with writing a tool for my company. I have 384 XML files that i have to read and parse with a SAX Parser into txt files.
What i got until now is the parsing of all XML-Files into one txt File, size 43 MB. With a BufferedReader and line.startsWith i want to extract all relevant information out of the textfile.

**Edit: Done**
(So my Problem is how to solve this more efficiently. I'm having an idea (but unfortunately not in code as you might think) but i dont know if its possible: I want to iterate through a Directory, find the XML-File i want, then parse it and create a new txt File with the parsed content. If done for all 384 XML files i want the same thing for the 384 txt files, read them with a BufferedReader to get my relevant information. Its important to read them one at a time. Another Problem is the Directory path, its a bit complex: "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Data\ProjectName\A1\1\1SLin\wanted.xml" for each file there is a own directory. The variable is A1, it reaches from A-P and 1-24. Alternatively I have all the relevant files with thir absolute path in an arraylist, so its also okay to iterate over this list if its easier.)

**Edit:**
I came to a solution: Below contains the search directories method and a method to parse the xml Files of a List into the same directory with the same filename but another file extension

```
public List<File> searchFile(File dir, String find) {

    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    List<File> matches = new ArrayList<File>();
    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                matches.addAll(searchFile(files[i], find));
            } else if (files[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(find)) {
                matches.add(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(matches);
    return matches;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Import_Files im = new Import_Files();
    File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\MS-Daten\\");
    String name = "snp_result_5815.xml";
    List<File> matches = im.searchFile(dir, name);
    System.out.println(matches);

    for (int i=0; i<matches.size(); i++) {
        String j = String.valueOf(i);
        String xml_name = matches.get(i).getAbsolutePath();
        File f = new File(matches.get(i).getAbsolutePath().replaceFirst(".xml", ".txt"));
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(f)));

        System.out.println("\nstarting File: "+ i + "\n");
        xml_parse myReader = new xml_parse(xml_name);
        myReader.setContentHandler(new MyContentHandler());
        myReader.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
        myReader.run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `searchFolder` method below will take a path and file extension, search the path and all sub-directories, and pass any matching file types to the `processFile` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "c:\\temp";
    Pattern filePattern = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\.xml$");
    searchFolder(path, filePattern);
}

public static void searchFolder(String searchPath, Pattern filePattern){
    File dir = new File(searchPath);
    for(File item : dir.listFiles()){
        if(item.isDirectory()){
            //recursively search subdirectories
            searchFolder(item.getAbsolutePath(), filePattern);
        } else if(item.isFile() && filePattern.matcher(item.getName()).matches()){
            processFile(item);
        }
    }
}

public static void processFile(File aFile){
    String filename = aFile.getAbsolutePath();
    String txtFilename = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".txt";
    //Do your xml file parsing and write to txtFilename
}
```

The complexity of the path makes no difference, just specify the root path to search (looks like `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Data\ProjectName` in your case) and it will find all the files.

Comment: Thanks. two more questions: i need a specified filename, because in every directory there are more than one .xml files and i want to choose one manually. second is, if i do the parsing in processFile(), how should i realize the writing? because the actual writing (system.out.println()) is defined in the contentehandler class. Am i able to define a new File in another class and set the write command in the content handler class?

Comment: I've updated the code to use a regular expression rather than just matching the file extension. Just create a regular expression that will match the files you want. As for writing the txt file, do that however you like, in the `processFile` method you've got all the information you need to get started.